# How to thread with Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Firstly, is it standard to have one master thread (`t2` in my case), starting and ending all other threads (`t1`)?

```
require 'curses'
include Curses

init_screen

def counter(window_name, positionx, positiony, times_factor, sleep_factor)
  window_name = Window.new(10,10,positionx,positiony)
  window_name.box('|', '-')
  window_name.setpos(2, 3)
  window_name.addstr(window_name.inspect)
  times_factor.times do |i|
    window_name.setpos(1, 1)
    window_name.addstr(i.to_s)
    window_name.refresh
    sleep sleep_factor  
  end
end
def thread1
  counter("One",10,10,50,0.01)
  counter("Two",20,20,200,0.01)
  counter("Three",30,30,3,1.0)
end
def thread2
  t1 = Thread.new{thread1()}
  x = 4
  chars = ["   ","*  ","** ","***","***","** ","*  ","   "]
  four = Window.new(20,20,10,100)
  four.box('|', '-')
  four.setpos(1, 1)
  i = 3
  while t1.alive?
    four.setpos(1, 1)
    four.addstr chars[0]   
    four.addstr i.to_s
    four.refresh
    sleep 0.1  
    chars.push chars.shift
  end
  t1.join
end

t2 = Thread.new{thread2()}
t2.join
```

Secondly, how can I change the `while t1.alive?` loop so that rather than simply displaying a star animation during the operation of `t1`, I can give feedback on what is actually happening within the `t1` thread? E.g.,

```
counter1 has now finished
counter2 has now finished
counter3 has now finished
```

To do this, will each counter method actually have to be in its own thread within `t1`? Within the `while t1.alive?` loop, should I have a case loop that continually tests which loop is currently alive?

This approach would mean the whole program is happening at once, rather than following the order its written in. Is this how larger programs actually work? Is this how I should give feedback? Only telling the user when a certain thread has been joined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thread1` call `counter` serially; So they are excutedly one after another.

Following is the modified code.

```
def thread1(count)
  lock = Mutex.new
  dec_count = proc { lock.synchronize { count[0] -= 1 } }
  threads = []
  threads << Thread.new { counter("One",10,10,50,0.01); dec_count.call }
  threads << Thread.new { counter("Two",20,20,200,0.01); dec_count.call }
  threads << Thread.new { counter("Three",30,30,3,1.0); dec_count.call }
  threads.each(&:join)
end

def thread2
  active_count = [3]
  t1 = Thread.new{thread1(active_count)}
  chars = ["   ","*  ","** ","***","***","** ","*  ","   "]
  four = Window.new(3,20,10,30)
  four.box('|', '-')
  four.setpos(1, 1)
  while t1.alive?
    four.setpos(1, 1)
    four.addstr chars[0]
    four.addstr active_count[0].to_s
    four.refresh
    sleep 0.1
    chars.push chars.shift
  end
  t1.join
end

init_screen
thread2
```

**UPDATE**

In the original code `window_name` was overwritten. In the following, I replaced the name of the parameter to prevent that.

```
def counter(thread_name, positiony, positionx, times_factor, sleep_factor)
  window_name = Window.new(10, 10, positiony, positionx)
  window_name.box('|', '-')
  window_name.setpos(2, 3)
  window_name.addstr(thread_name)
  times_factor.times do |i|
    window_name.setpos(1, 1)
    window_name.addstr(i.to_s)
    window_name.refresh
    sleep sleep_factor
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When You join a thread You actually say to Ruby interpreter to wait while this thread finishes running, so no feedback. What You can do is to run each counter operation in separate thread. Here is a small example, use it modify Your code

```
require "open-uri"

th2 = Thread.new do
  threads = ["first", "second", "third"].map do |i|
    Thread.new do
      open("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341175/how-to-thread-with-ruby")
      Thread.current["status"] = "opened #{i} time"
    end
  end
  threads.each { |th| th.join; puts th["status"] }
end

th2.join
```